# Heißt es „ein Jahr gültig“, „für ein Jahr gültig“ oder „ein Jahr lang gültig“?

Tags: adjective

Es geht um die Gültigkeit einer Abokarte.

Ist diese ab dem 1. November eigentlich

- a) ein Jahr gültig
- b) für ein Jahr gültig
- c) ein Jahr lang gültig
- d) für ein Jahr lang gültig

Sind alle vier Formulierungen richtig oder nur eine davon? Je länger ich darüber nachdenke, desto weniger bin ich mir sicher.

Comment: oder e) gültig für ein Jahr?

Comment: @AdInfinitum Das ist denke ich nur eine Variation zu "für ein Jahr gültig". # "Die Karte ist für ein Jahr gültig" == "Die Karte ist gültig für ein Jahr."

Comment: *Für ein Jahr lang* geht m. E. **nicht**, weil *für ein Jahr* ja bereits ausführlich *für einen Zeitraum von einem Jahr* bedeutet.

Comment: Ich würde, um alle Verwechslungsmöglichkeiten auszuschließen, schreiben: "Gültig für 12 Monate". Damit ist klar, dass die Gültigkeit nicht an ein Kalenderjahr gebunden ist, sondern z.B. vom 1.11.2016 bis 31.10.2017 gelten kann.

Answer (score 2):

alle drei Formen sind valide. Du kannst sagen: Diese Karte ist ein Jahr gültig. Diese Karte ist für ein Jahr gültig. Und Diese Karte ist ein Jahr lang gültig.

Wenn ich Deinen Namen richtig interpretiere, machst Du das für einen Auftraggeber. Frag den doch mal, was er besser findet.

Edit: Die vierte Version ist auch korrekt, also anwendbar, aber eher umgangssprachlich. Wenn du das für einen Auftrag verwendest, solltest du vielleicht wirklich den Auftraggeber fragen, was er für besser hält.

Comment: Drei oder vier?

Comment: @MartinPeters In der Originalfrage gab es drei Formen; a,b und c. Und Karsten hat die Frage in der Zwischenzeit beantwortet aber nach einer Weile hat Iris die Frage bearbeitet und die vierte Option hinzugefügt.

Answer (score 1):

Die 4. Variante ist grammatikalisch inkorrekt, weil sowohl **für** als auch **lang** auf eine Zeitdauer hinweisen. Die 2. und 3. Variante sind dementsprechend korrekt.

Die 1. Variante ist die Kurzform der 3. Variante und wird umgangssprachlich häufiger verwendet. Im Duden findet man unter dem Begriff *Jahr* nur diese Beispiele: zwei, viele Jahre lang; das ging ein Jahr lang gut. In Gesetzestexten findet man ebenfalls die 3. Variante, wie z.B.: "Ein Prospekt ist nach seiner Billigung *zwölf Monate lang* für öffentliche Angebote oder Zulassungen zum Handel an einem organisierten Markt *gültig* (...) ist nach seiner Billigung bis zu *zwölf Monate lang gültig*" (§ 9 WpPG).
Eine alternative Variante wäre noch:

Die Gültigkeitsdauer der Abokarte beträgt 12 Monate ab dem (Datum).